Merge the headphone tags?
There's the [headphones] and the [headphone] tag (plural, non-plural). I suppose these should be merged. I saw them while drafting a question.

I had a quick look and you are absolutely right. A couple of questions had both tags on!
I have merged the 7 with headphone into the 150-ish with headphones and set up a synonym for them.
